# Qual melhor forma de fazer animações para android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animação

Estou para começar um sistema para android que possui diversas animações que interagem de acordo com o que o usuário faz, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor ferramenta ou framework para conseguir desenvolver essas animações para android?

Alguns exemplos de interação são as seguintes:

- Existe um personagem no sistema, como se fosse um mascote, onde ele pode falar, no caso aparece um balão com fala de acordo com a interação, esse mascote pode andar.
- No background existe um elevador, onde as portas desse elevador pode abrir e fechar, as luzes acender ou desligar, mas tudo animando.
- Outra função é mover e redimensionar objetos na tela, exemplo começo com uma sala vazia, e posso adicionar um quadro e mover esse quadro para onde quero que fique na sala, e aumentar e diminuir esse quadro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que a melhor biblioteca para trabalhar animações no Android seja a [Nineold](http://nineoldandroids.com). Ela implementa as animações baseadas nos *ValueAnimators* que foram apresentados no Android 4.0.

Mas pelo que você descreveu do seu projeto, talvez valha a pena olhar algumas *game engines* para Android. Talvez facilite a sua vida. Para isso, recomendo a [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org) ou o [Cocos2d](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/).